# Create a list of sequential numbers excluding one number

Tags: c#, linq

Requirements:

1. Create a list of `n` sequential numbers starting at `a`.
2. Exclude number `x`.

This is the best I have right now, the problem being that it creates `n + 1` numbers if `x` is not within the range.

```
var numbers = Enumerable
    .Range(a, numberOfDataRowsToAdd + 1)
    .Where(i => i != TechnicalHeaderRowIndex);
```

Example 1 should produce `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.

```
var a = 0;
var n = 10; 
var x = 11;
```

Example 2 should produce `0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10`.

```
var a = 0;
var n = 10; 
var x = 6;
```

[Here is a Fiddle that demonstrates Mark's answer.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pZuXT8)

Comment: Both examples list 11 numbers despite `n` being 10

Comment: @MarkSowul Catch. Not sure whether I should edit the question or not. Though I did because it seems not to have impacted the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
Enumerable.Range(a, n + 1)
          .Where(i => i != x)
          .Take(n);
```

Answer (score 2):

My example, how it can be done without LINQ and extra loop iterations:

```
 public static IEnumerable<int> GenerateNumbers(int a, int n, int x)
 {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a == x)
        {
           i--;
           a++;
           continue;
        }
        yield return a++;
    }
 }
```

But if you don't want create new method for this purpose, Mark Sowul or Jakub Lortz answers are better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be described as

1. Get `n + 1` sequential numbers starting from `a`
2. If `x` is in the range, remove `x`, otherwise remove the maximum number from the list

Translated to C#

```
int numberToExclude = Math.Min(n + a, x);
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(a, n + 1).Where(i => i != numberToExclude);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the last if your enumerable count is bigger than `numberOfDataRowsToAdd`

Extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DropLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
  return enumerable.Take(enumerable.Count()-1);
}
```

Usage:

```
var numbers = Enumerable
    .Range(a, numberOfDataRowsToAdd + 1)
    .Where(i => i != TechnicalHeaderRowIndex);

if(numbers.Count() > numberOfDataRowsToAdd)
    numbers = numbers.DropLast();
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to generate only necessary values instead of generating `n + 1` values and then remove `x`:

```
Enumerable.Range(a, n).Select(i => i < x ? i : i + 1);
```

Example 1: `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.
Example 2: `0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what really is the challenge - Linq shortest or fastest or just working. How about the natural (which should also be the fastest Linq based)

```
var numbers = a <= x && x < a + n ?
    Enumerable.Range(a, x - a).Concat(Enumerable.Range(x + 1, a - x + n)) :
    Enumarble.Range(a, n);
```